# Appropriate statistical tests for very limited-range (0, 1, 2) count data?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, count-data

I have some data from an experiment where participants from two different groups viewed a stimulus. There were 9 possible stimuli, distributed over 3 conditions (equivalent example: stimuli were all photos of two people. For the first condition, both participants had brown hair; For the second, both blonde; for the third, one brown and one blonde). Participants had to make two binary judgements about the stimuli (e.g. Person A hair colour: blonde or brown? Person B hair colour: blonde or brown?). The judgements were then scored as correct or incorrect, and summed to make a total score in the range of 0-2 for that particular stimulus. Participants viewed one stimulus from each condition.

I am interested in, primarily, a) whether participants produce judgements that are more accurate than chance, b) how participant group and stimulus condition interact with their score.

The dataset is relatively small (<100 participants), and moderately powered. Are standard parametric tests such as one-tailed t-tests (to test for better performance than chance) or a two-way ANOVA (total_score ~ group x condition) acceptable in this case? I know ANOVAs are generally robust to violations of their prerequisites, but I am concerned about the data range being so severely limited. Other options I considered include: some kind of count regression model (though those don't seem to be designed to deal with such a truncated data range), or a partial proportional odds model (which has an unfortunate lack of online documentation regarding acceptable use-cases, so I'm struggling to know if this is appropriate or not).

Comment: Do you have access to the original data? The summation discards information (and makes your life harder, as you are finding out). If you have the original data set including each separate stimulus condition, the participant ID and whether the response was correct, you could run a straightforward logistic regression, ideally a mixed model/repeated measures model with a random factor for the repeated measurement of each participant.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I do have access to the original data - I can edit the question to provide a mock dataframe if that would help understanding! The issue with logistic regression is that we think there may be interaction between the two judgements we asked for (e.g. in the mixed condition (one blonde, one brown) we think that participant group will affect how accurate they are on, e.g. judging brown but not blonde, perhaps)... So it's not really a binary dependent variable, it's a dependent variable that's a score out of two.

Comment: You can include interactions in (mixed model) logistic regressions.